# Unable to save worksheets in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy a group of worksheets from the current workbook and save them in a new workbook using the following subroutine.

```
worksheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet4")).Copy
With ActiveWorkbook
        .SaveAs Filename:=Environ("TEMP") & "\New3.xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        .Close SaveChanges:=False
End With
```

However nothing is happening. I noticed from running the debugger that it returns to the main subroutine after executing the first line.

I also tried using the name of the worksheets

```
 worksheets(Array("NestP", "NestR")).Copy
```

Comment: Each of the three sheets must be present  (1, 2, 4). Or whatever number of named sheets are present in the Copy stmt.  Since this is a macro in the activeworkbook, it needs to be saved as XLSM, not xlsx.

Comment: Yeah those worksheets do exists in the workbook and I change the file type to xlsm. Still the same problem

Comment: DId you keep in your mind (on Windows) that the copy will be stored in C:\Users\(YOUR USER)\AppData\Local\Temp\New1.xlsx?